# Is there any way to set JAVA_OPTS for TensorFlow process

Tags: java, hadoop, tensorflow

Now we use TensorFlow to load the models in HDFS. The model is larger than 1G and it throws OOM when reaching the heap size.

```
2018-05-21 13:26:34.339483: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
18/05/21 13:26:35 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from hdfs://namenode:port/saved_model/0/variables/variables
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from hdfs://namenode:port/saved_model/0/variables/variables
2018-05-21 13:26:40.479367: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 411041792 exceeds 10% of system memory.
hdfsPread: NewByteArray error:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

TensorFlow is using `libhdfs` now and it may expose some ways to set the `JAVA_OPTS` with parameters or environment variables.

Comment: libhdfs is a C library, though

Comment: What is the batch size you are using? What the memory available on the executor running the job? Can u show how you are triggering the job?

Comment: This is triggered by loading the model from HDFS before training. And it works if we load the model from local host. So it would be the problem of default heap size of jvm to access HDFS files.

Comment: Update: It works when we run the same script in CentOS server with 128G memory but fails in MacOS with 8G memory. We have used the pre-built `libhdfs.so` which may works only in x86-64 server which needs more than 8G memory for 1G model in Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this will work for libhdfs: `export LIBHDFS_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m"`.